# Proving G/N is simple if N is a normal subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that G is a group and N < G a normal subgroup. Assume that there is no normal subgroup M < G with N < M. Prove that G/N is simple.

I am not really 100% sure where to start here. I feel like I may be missing something obvious but I'm not really sure. I know based off the information that N is the smallest normal subgroup of G, and that simple groups' normal subgroups are only the identity and themselves, so I can see the connection, I just can't see HOW to actually connect them

Comment: It isn't saying that $N$ is small.  It is saying that there are no normal subgroups that contain it.  In a sense, $N$ is big.

Comment: I meant that N was the smallest normal subgroup, is that incorrect?

Comment: Since no normal subgroup contains $N$, it is maximal.  That's kind of like being a largest normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p:G\rightarrow G/N$ the projection map and $L$ be a normal subgroup of $G/N$ different of $G/N$, $p^{-1}(L)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ which contains $N$, the hypothesis implies  that $p^{-1}(L)=N$ and $L$ is the trivial group. This is equivalent to saying that $G/N$ is simple.

Comment: Because $p^{-1}(L)$ contains $N$ since it contains $p^{-1}(e)=N$ and it is normal, the results follows from the fact that there is not a normal subgroup which contains $N$ and which is different from $N$ and $G$.

Comment: I think I am confused by what a quotient group actually does then. Does G/N then make all elements of N the identity? since p^(-1)((e))=N

Comment: yes, it makes all elements the identity. Since $p(x)=p(y)$ .e $xy^{-1}\in N$ in particular take $x=n\in N, y=e$, $p(n)=p(e)$.

Comment: I think you had a formatting error with the .e part