# Find a group of order 5784 that does not have a normal subgroup of index 12

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

This is a second part of a two-part question.

In the first part I was asked to prove that any group of order $5784 = 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 241$  has subgroups of the following *indexes*: $3, 6, 8, 12,$ and $24$.

I proved that part by showing:

- G has subgroups of orders $2, 2^2, 2^3, 3, 241$ (by Sylow theorem).
- Moreover, the subgroup of $241$, lets call it H, is normal since by Sylow's third theorem its easy to see its the only subgroup of that order.
- Therefore for any other subgroup of $G$, $K$, $HK$ is a subgroup as well (since HK = KH due to H normal)
- But the order of HK is $o(HK) = \frac{o(H) \cdot o(K)}{o(H \cap K)} = o(H) \cdot o(K)$ since necessarily $o(H\cap K) = 1$ due to order of H being prime and any other subgroup will not have order that is a multiple of that prime (241)
- Therefore we have subgroups of orders: $241$, $241 \cdot 2$, $241 \cdot 2^2$, $241 \cdot 2^3$, $241 \cdot 3$, which give us the subgroups of required indexes (24, 12, 6, 3, 8 respectively) as well, QED.

Now to prove that there is a specific group of such order that does *not* have a normal subgroup of index 12, I suppose I need to show that there is such a group where there is more than one subgroup of index 12 (which is of order 241*2 = 482) and somehow prove that it is not equal to all of its conjugates in G, e.g. $g^{-1}Hg$?
Perhaps via some arithmetical considerations involving Sylow's third theorem I can show that there is theoretically a possibility for such group?

Comment: Hint: find such a group of order 24, then use a direct product.

Comment: @SteveD hmm do you mean something like - construct $G = S_4 \otimes (\mathbb{Z}_{241},+)$ as the direct product of the symmetric group on 4 elements and the finite cyclic group of order 241. this is a group of order 5784 but since $S_4$ does not have a normal subgroup of index 12 and neither does cyclic group of prime order 241 I can somehow ascertain that the direct product does not have such a subgroup either?

Comment: A normal subgroup of index 12 must contain your normal 241-subgroup, so quotient it out and work there.

Comment: I can see why the group must contain my normal 241-subgroup, can't make it further.. any further clues appreciated.. would I be looking at quotient G/H or H/K ( where G is the 5784-group and H, K are the subgroups of orders 482 and 241 respectively)? how would I tie that quotient group back to what I'm trying to prove? isomorphism theorems or anything of the like?

Comment: By any chance,  did you learn about the class equation?

Comment: Let $G=S_4\times P$ as you said. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of index $12$, then $P\le N$, as the only Sylow 241-subgroup. Thus $N/P$ is index $12$ in $G/P$...

Comment: I think I got it (finally.. thanks for patience). So G/P ~ S4, and only subgroup of index 12 in S4 is A4. But then N/P ~ A4 and A4 is normal in S4, therefore implying N/P  is normal, which is impossible because N/P is simple when P is normal in N and contained in no other normal subgroup in P thats not P itself (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164553/proving-g-n-is-simple-if-n-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-g)

Comment: No that's not right. You're mixing up "order 12" and "index 12". You're right to look at $N/P$, but it's order **2**.

Comment: @SteveD ok last attempt before I switch careers: by the (third) isomorphism theorem $(N/P) \unlhd (G/P)$ but as we said this would imply a subgroup of order 2 being normal in S4 but S4 does not have any normal subgroups of order 2

Comment: Yup, perfect! :)

Comment: Lol thank you for bearing with me I actually learned a lot from working my way through it so thank you good sir @SteveD

Comment: Last step is to write an answer of your own (and accept it) so this question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the answer I arrived at with the kind help of @SteveD in the comment thread above:

Consider the group  = $S_4 \times C_{241}$.

As the direct product of $S_4$ (the symmetric group on 4 elements, of order 4! = 24), and the finite cyclic group of order 241, this is a group of order 5784, as needed.

Assume it has a normal subgroup N of index 12.

Then N has order 5784/12 = 482. Note that 482 = 241 * 2 which is of the form $p \cdot q$ for two primes. Therefore (by Cauchy theorem) it has a subgroup of order 241.
Further, this must be the one and the same group $C_{241}$ since there is only a single *unique* subgroup of this order in G (by Sylow's third theorem which constraints the number of sylow subgroups of a given order that can exist, in this case the conditions are easily seen to imply a single subgroup).

So we have $N \unlhd G$, $C_{241} \unlhd G$ and $C_{241} \unlhd N$, therefore by the third isomorphism theorem we have $ N / C_{241} \unlhd G / C_{241}$.

But $G / C_{241} \simeq S_4$ (by construction of G) and $o(N/C_{241}) = [N : C_{241}] = 2$, which is a contradiction since the symmetric group $S_4$ does not have any normal subgroups of order 2. QED.